# Node js file uploading process, where is the error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've just started node.js https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp I'm learning from this site, most of the codes give errors. I think oldpath comes with empty value...

my codes:

```js
var http = require("http");
var formidable = require("formidable");
var fs = require("fs");
http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url == "/fileupload") {
      var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
      form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        var oldpath = files.filetoupload.filepath;
        var newpath = "C:/Users/sahin/" + files.filetoupload.originalFilename;
        fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
          res.write("File uploaded and moved!");
          res.end();
        });
      });
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      res.write(
        '<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'
      );
      res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
      res.write('<input type="submit">');
      res.write("</form>");
      return res.end();
    }
  })
  .listen(8080);
```

error:

```bash
node:internal/fs/utils:696

throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(propName, \['string', 'Buffer', 'URL'\], path);

^
TypeError \[ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE\]: The "oldPath" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined
at Object.rename (node:fs:1019:13)
at C:\\Users\\sahin\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\nodejs\\index.js:11:10
at zalgoSafe (C:\\Users\\sahin\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\node_modules\\dezalgo\\dezalgo.js:20:10)
at f (C:\\Users\\sahin\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\node_modules\\once\\once.js:25:25)
at IncomingForm.\<anonymous\> (C:\\Users\\sahin\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\node_modules\\formidable\\dist\\index.cjs:1210:7)
at IncomingForm.emit (node:events:517:28)
at IncomingForm.\_maybeEnd (C:\\Users\\sahin\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\node_modules\\formidable\\dist\\index.cjs:1661:10)
at C:\\Users\\sahin\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\node_modules\\formidable\\dist\\index.cjs:1420:14
at Array.\<anonymous\> (C:\\Users\\sahin\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\node_modules\\formidable\\dist\\index.cjs:88:7)
at finish (node:internal/streams/writable:745:25) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
Node.js v18.18.0

\[nodemon\] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I looked for videos online that do this and did the same but I always get this error, I think the oldpath file is null

Comment: Please fix your code formatting—it's currently very hard to read.

Comment: I guess it is okay.

Comment: For what it's worth, w3schools is fairly well known as a terrible site for tutorials—I'm unsuprised that this code doesn't work.

Comment: `files.filetoupload[0]` instead of `files.filetoupload`

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: like @SuperStormer said, change `files.filetoupload.filepath` to `files.filetoupload[0].filepath` and `files.filetoupload.originalFilename` to `files.filetoupload[0].originalFilename` . It works for me

Comment: Yes It works now

Comment: I just started node js thank you both very much

Comment: how did you solve the problem or where did you find the solution?